# actionMenuTextColor not working when using ?/attr

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to change the color of the text menu item in my toolbar

When using :

```
<style name="Base.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/blue</item>
```

It works but when using :

```
<style name="Base.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
```

It doesn't.

Any idea?

Edit 1 :

toolbar styling is the following

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.App.Toolbar</item>

<style name="Widget.App.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar</item>
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Widget.App.Toolbar.TitleTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Toolbar.TitleTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.App.Headline6">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

Edit 2 :

using

```
<style name="Base.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
```

actually works. But again, not `colorPrimary`

Comment: Post also your Toolbar.

Comment: Has ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar a parent?

Comment: No, it doesn't : 

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorApp4</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>

Comment: Does `actionMenuTextColor` look like `colorApp4`?

Comment: ?attr/colorPrimary is blue 
colorApp4 is white

Comment: Ok but using `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>` does it look like white?

Comment: yes it does, it ends up being white rather than blue (when i use @color/blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
```

It doesn't use the `colorPrimary` because in the `Toolbar` you are overriding the `colorPrimary` with:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar</item>      
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent=""> 
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorApp4</item>  <!-- HERE -->
</style>
```

It means that using `?attr/colorPrimary` the `actionMenuTextColor` uses the `colorApp4` in the `Toolbar`.

If you want to change the default color just apply:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Toolbar" parent=""> 
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorApp4</item>  
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">......</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is correct, but then how come if i don't override actionMenuTextColor, then the items in my menu are not in the color of colorPrimary ?

Comment: @user2230304 I should check the styles to find the default value.

Comment: That doesn't work if i use     <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item> because as you said i ovewrite it.

So the work around i've found is to use Toolbar.Surface instead of Toolbar.Primary

This way i keep my colorPrimary untouched :

<item name="colorSurface">?attr/colorApp4</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>

this one works